# Specifying custom date range in SQL query

Tags: sql, database, date

I want to write a query where in I need to specify the custom range (instead of hardcoded date range) for date starting from the order day.  In the table being used,  I have the date for the order.

As of now I have hardcoded the date range like:

```
where owh.order_day between TO_DATE('2016/07/15','YYYY/MM/DD') and TO_DATE('2017/01/17','YYYY/MM/DD')
```

where order_day is a date.

But rather I want something like:

```
where owh.order_day between TO_DATE(owh.order_day - 1,'YYYY/MM/DD') and TO_DATE(owh.order_day +3,'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

I am doing  "-1" as it's "between", so it will take from order_day - order_day+2

For example, If the order_day is: "17/01/2016" then I want the condition to be where the date range is dynamically calculated as: "16/01/2016 - 20/01/2016" .
Is something like this possible? If yes, how can we achieve in in SQL??

The DB in question is Oracle
Any leads appreciated

Comment: SQL Server does not have a `to_date()` function.  What database are you using?

Comment: Its a company specific db. Is this possible generally in any sql query?

Comment: This question makes no sense at all.  You want to compare `order_day` to a range based on `order_day`.  Edit your question (or ask another one).  Tag with the correct database you are using.  Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I have added the example for clarity. And the date range is essentially based on the value of order_day

Comment: Does it depend on DB. My question is in general for any db.

Comment: `where owh.order_day between TO_DATE(owh.order_day - 1,'YYYY/MM/DD') and TO_DATE(owh.order_day +3,'YYYY/MM/DD')`, if it worked, it would be ***EQUIVALENT*** to `where TRUE`.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. A single date will **always** be between the day before that date and the date three days later. You can just remove that condition. Your question also isn't clearly "DBMS independent" because `to_date()` isn't standard SQL. And if that is Oracle or Postgres, then calling `to_date()` on a `DATE` columns is totally senseless.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Hi sorry for net telling before, the DB is oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not told us which RDBMS you are using, and since you are saying "any leads appreciated", I suppose we are free to give an answer for any RDBMS.  The following will work for MySQL:

```
BETWEEN DATE_SUB( somedate, INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AND DATE_ADD( somedate, INTERVAL 1 DAY )
```

(source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-date-functions.htm#function_date-add)